# Hibernate Criteria to find Duplicates

Tags: java, count, group-by, hibernate-criteria

I want to get the duplicate entries. I want to use the query as criteria, for this i am using the below code.

```
SELECT * from A 
WHERE field in (
     SELECT field from A 
     GROUP BY field HAVING COUNT(field) > 1
);
```

The Hibernate mapping is like

```
@Entity
class A{
    ...
    private String field;
    ...
}
```

How can I get list of A that have duplication in 'field' column?

Answer (score 3):

You can pretty much translate your query one to one to [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html) (warning: untested).

```
select A
from A a 
where a.field in (
   select ai.field 
   from A ai
   group by ai.field -- assumes that by f you mean field 
   having count(a1.field) > 1
)
```

Comment: I would follow up the question with "why it must be a criteria query?" (and if the answer is "because that is what is used on other methods of my project" don't bother, it is not a good reason). Anyway, if you want to stick with criterias keep in mind that you will be forced to write a long, hackish, hard to read and slower query than the HQL version. The reason for this is that hibernate criteria does not support the having clause. While there are [known workarounds](http://fokot.blogspot.com.br/2011/06/having-clause-in-hibernate-criteria-no.html) I would definitively do it with HQL.

Comment: Also that a look at Hibernate [Patch HHH-1043 - Added HAVING Support to Criteria](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1043) open since October of 2005.

Comment: you are right. My main answer to your question is "just because". Just because I want to deeply understand what I can do with Criteria and how it can be easy. Since the next queries will be more complicated seems that I have to use HQL.

Comment: If you are pushing the edges for learning purposes you might as well try the [JPA 2+ Criteria API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/persistence-criteria.htm#GJITV). While I still think that it is a bit verbose, it is type safe and supports having clauses. [Sample query](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/group#GROUP_BY_and_HAVING_in_Criteria_Queries_).

Answer (score 1):

My own answer according prompted [Anthony Accioly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/664577/anthony-accioly)

```
final Criteria searchCriteria = session.createCriteria(A.class);

...

final DetachedCriteria d1 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class);
d1.setProjection(Projections.count("field"));
d1.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("field", "AA.field"));

final DetachedCriteria d2 = DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class, "AA");
d2.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.groupProperty("field")));
d2.add(Subqueries.lt(1L, d1));

criteria.add(Property.forName("field").in(d2));
```

Comment: Cool workaround (`where 1 < select count(aa.field)`). Anyway, anyone reading that in 2014 should refer to the new [Criteria Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch12.html), the typesafe JPA 2 style Criteria API is now standard (and the old Criteria API is considered deprecated).